# I want to convert CSV to JSON file using python

Tags: javascript, python

```
import csv
import json


# defining the function to convert CSV file to JSON file
def convjson(cleanedhm, js):
    # creating a dictionary
    mydata = {}

    # reading the data from CSV file
    with open(cleanedhm, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csvRead = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        # Converting rows into dictionary and adding it to data
        for rows in csvRead:
            mykey = rows['hmid']
            mydata[mykey] = rows

            # dumping the data
    with open('cleanedhm', encoding='utf-8') as jsonfile:
        jsonfile.write(json.dumps(mydata, indent=4))

    # filenames


cleanedhm = r'mydatalist.csv'
js = r'mydatalist.json'

# Calling the convjson function
convjson(cleanedhm, js)
```

Comment: Do you have any question ? Is there any error ?

Comment: I'm having one feed file

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output as well as explain what your problem is. At the moment you pass `js` parameter, but never use it in the body of the function. Also `DictReader` will return `dict` so not sure what you are doing when _Converting rows into dictionary and adding it to data_ (according to the comment in the code).

Comment: Please, check [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is a really great tool, and in this case it does what you need in two very easy lines!

```py
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the CSV file is saved\File Name.csv')
csv.to_json (r'Path where the new JSON file will be stored\New File Name.json')
```

Comment: It's unclear what problem has OP with their code and also using pandas just for that is overkill.

Comment: @buran How is it overkill? ```read_csv()``` and ```to_json()``` are meant to be used. and I would argue 2 lines of code is worth an import compared to 10x that amount of code

Comment: Well, installing big third-party library with a lot of dependecies, just to convert csv to json that can be done with few lines just with Standard Library? Oh, yes, it's overkill. If they already use it - then yes.

Comment: can anyone of you please share the complete script for CSV to JSON Conversion

Comment: @HemanthTadepalli What I posted beside the file paths which are specific to you is complete code. That is all you need to convert a csv to json.

Comment: And by the way, conversion with csv and json modules is just 4 lines, incl. the import statements, not 10x times more (same essential functionality that you provide, hard coded names, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

process your file with pandas as a DataFrame and then export with the to_json() method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).